# Keeping Headers with table in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am having trouble keeping titles and tables together in ms word.

Say I have something like this:

```
Table Name
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
Content |Content |Content
Content |Content |Content
```

Where 'Table Name' is Heading 1, if the table is large it will automatically split Heading 1 and the Table and put the table on the next page.

I'm looking for something like a `keep lines together` function for the header and table.

The reason why I use the header style instead of a caption is because I need the headers to show up on a navigation pane. This is another reason why I can't put the header inside the table either.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure out how to do it by selecting `allow row to break across pages` in `table properties` and then making sure the `specify height` button is unchecked.